# Backbone setinterval ( Update all models from collection in 10 sec interval...)

Tags: json, backbone.js, setinterval

Please How Can I update my View every 10 sec ? Or is there way rerender or refetch this view only when is something changed in my json file ?

**My Main js :**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "" : "categories",

},

initialize: function () {
    this.headerView = new HeaderView();
    $('.header').html(this.headerView.el);
},    

categories: function () {
    if (!this.CategoriesView) {
        this.CategoriesView = new CategoriesView();
    }
    $('#content').html(this.CategoriesView.el);
    this.headerView.selectMenuItem('categories-menu');
},




utils.loadTemplate(['HeaderView'], function() {
app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();

});
```

**My Collection :**

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: 'api/categories_and_products.json'
});
```

**JSON :**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Pizza",
        "id": 1,
        "products": [{ "name" : "Romana"},{"name" : "Viennese"},{"name" : "Capricciosa"},{"name" : "Quattro formaggi"},{"name" : "Bianca"},{"name" : "Alla casalinga"}]
    },
    {
        "title": "Pasta",
        "id": 2,
        "products": [{ "name" : "Spagetti Napolitana"},{"name" : "Penne Arrabiata"},{"name" : "Tagliatelle with cream sauce"},{"name" : "Tortellini"}]
    }
]
```

**My HTML template for categories :**

```
<script type="text/template" id="categories-template">        
    <% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>
        <li class="categorycls"><%= category.get('title') %></li>

        <% _.each(category.get("products"), function(product) { %>

            <li class="productscls">
            <%= product.name %>                       

            </li>

        <% }); %>
    <% }); %>                   
</script>
```

**This is view which I wanna have always updated :**

```
var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

initialize:function () {
    this.render(this);
    this.loop();
},
loop:function(){
    setInterval(function() { this.render() }, 1000)
},
render:function (that) {

    var categories = new Categories();        
    categories.fetch({
        success: function (categories) {            
        var template = _.template($('#categories-template').html(), {categories: categories.models});           
          that.$el.html(template);
        }
    })
}             
});
```

I don't know how rerender or refetch ...I need new data from json updated without refresh website manualy...

Now every 10 sec in console is error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'render'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added one `function loop` which will call render on every 10 seconds

```
var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    initialize:function () {

        this.render(this);
        this.loop();

    },
    loop:function(){

        //setInterval(render,10*1000);

        //[Edit]
        setInterval(this.render(this),10*1000);
    },

    //render:function () {
    //var that = this;

    //[Edit]

    render:function (that) {

        var categories = new Categories();        
        categories.fetch({
            success: function (categories) {            
            var template = _.template($('#categories-template').html(), {categories:     categories.models});           
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })

    }             
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but your code not function me ...

Uncaught ReferenceError: render is not defined

Comment: @MatejMarko I got your point. I had written `setInterval(rander` by mistake error is due to it. now I have updated code to `setInterval(this.rander`.

Comment: thanks I have repaired your code but now I have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined

Comment: I think that issue caused by different scope of window and your backbone CategoriesView.

could you please try it :
setInterval.call(this,this.render,10*1000);

Comment: thnks Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation  :/

Comment: No Categories is not rendered .... Only notice in console 
    TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: Thanks now working but when I change some value in json file still need refresh website manualy ....Data is not updated...

Comment: `render` doesn't return a function so how can `setInterval(this.render(this), ...)` work at all? Why not `setInterval(function() { that.render() }, ...)` and skip the argument to `render`?

Comment: I change to setInterval(function() { this.render(this) }, 1000) or setInterval(function() { this.render() }, 1000) and in console is still Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'render'

Comment: @MatejMarko could you please edit your question by add your complete code, means required html,js,css and json file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way would be

```
    loop:function(){
         var that = this;
         clearInterval(some.globally.defined.interval);
         some.globally.defined.interval = setInterval(function(){
             that.render()
         },interval);
    }
```